# Git push hangs on TOTAL

Tags: git

Git suddenly started to hang on `PUSH` command. I
searched over other questions but the solutions didn't work.

I am on ubuntu 12.04.

```
Counting objects: 18, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
Writing objects: 100% (13/13), 2.57 KiB, done.
Total 13 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

It was working 5 minutes ago on larger files. Internet connection is perfect.

It works perfectly on another repository on the same server and on the same development machine.

Comment: so does it do the same if you try to push from another computer, or another clone of the same repo in the same computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repo was corrupted, had to clone again and copy the changes manually in the new cloned directory

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same problem. I just use this two command and it worked for me.
`git pull` then `git push`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).